# Extract two dates, result in seconds (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to extract two dates and presents the result in seconds. I do:

```
dftask['TimeWindowDuration'] = dftask['LatestEnd'] - dftask['EarliestStart']
```

The LatestEnd and EarliestStart are both: `datetime64[ns]`

The corresponding output dataframe:

```
    LatestEnd   EarliestStart   TimeWindowDuration
27-7-2015 22:57 27-7-2015 22:14 0 days 00:43:00.000000000
28-7-2015 6:20  28-7-2015 1:50  0 days 04:30:00.000000000
28-7-2015 6:45  27-7-2015 20:32 0 days 10:13:00.000000000
28-7-2015 7:00  27-7-2015 21:47 0 days 09:13:00.000000000
28-7-2015 6:15  28-7-2015 1:45  0 days 04:30:00.000000000
```

How to specify that the TimeWindowDuration is in seconds? `unit='s'`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Alex.S do not know what is wrong about my post? I provide code, an example, and the results? And it is minimal too.

Comment: I tried to execute the code you provided ang guess what happened.

Comment: Exactly what are you trying for? I believe timedelta already has precision till seconds )or even naneseconds) i think

Comment: I would like to change the output format of TimeWindowDuration to seconds. With this format I can not do calculations within Excel, because Excel does not recognize the date format (0 days 00:43:00.00000). It doesn't even recognize that it is a date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `timedelta.total_seconds()` as:

```
dftask['TimeWindowDuration'].total_seconds()
```

Example:

```
d1 = datetime(2015, 10, 1, 10, 56, 21)
d2 = datetime(2015, 10, 1, 10, 58, 21)
d3 = d2-d1

In [21]: d3.total_seconds()
Out[21]: 120.0
```

EDIT:

Let:

```
In [5]: import pandas as pd

In [6]: a = pd.to_timedelta('0 days 00:43:00.000000000',unit='s')

In [7]: a
Out[7]: Timedelta('0 days 00:43:00')

In [8]: a.total_seconds()
Out[8]: 2580.0
```

Hope that helps.

EDIT 2:

In your dataframe:

```
dftask['TimeWindowDuration'] = (dftask['LatestEnd'] - dftask['EarliestStart']).dt.seconds
```

Remember to read the dataframe or parse the columns as dates with `parse_dates=['LatestEnd','EarliestStart']`.

Comment: Hi @Fabio thanks for your reply, but it results in: Series' object has no attribute 'total_seconds' , while Timewindowduration = timedelta64[ns]

Comment: May you edit your question with a sample of your original dataframe so we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: I changed the post, and added the dataframe

Comment: thanks for your edit. I can reproduce your example, but how to implement it with my dataframe? If I do:         temp = pd.to_timedelta(dftask['TimeWindowDuration'], unit='s')
        dftask['TimeWindowDuration'] = temp.total_seconds() it reproduces the same error.